# Prolog: Tick-tack-toe game

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I have basic Tick-tack-toe game, where 2 players both make moves on a grid of 9 cells. The problem is that after the frist player makes the last and winnig move, the game doesnt stop and player 2 still can play. And if second player, somehow, makes winning move too, he will be the winner, despite player 1 actually getting the win first. It doesnt make same error if second player wins frist. Draw works fine. Here`s the code:

```
:- dynamic o/1.
:- dynamic x/1.

/* the various combinations of a successful horizontal, vertical
or diagonal line */

ordered_line(1,2,3).
ordered_line(4,5,6).
ordered_line(7,8,9).
ordered_line(1,4,7).
ordered_line(2,5,8).
ordered_line(3,6,9).
ordered_line(1,5,9).
ordered_line(3,5,7).

/*line predicate to complete lines

line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(A,B,C).
line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(A,C,B).
line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(B,A,C).
line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(B,C,A).
line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(C,A,B).
line(A,B,C) :- ordered_line(C,B,A).


full(A) :- x(A).
full(A) :- o(A).

empty(A) :- not(full(A)).

all_full :- full(1),full(2),full(3),full(4),full(5),
full(6),full(7),full(8),full(9).


done :- ordered_line(A,B,C), x(A), x(B), x(C), write('Player 2 win.'),nl.

done :- ordered_line(A,B,C), o(A), o(B), o(C), write('Player 1 win.'),nl.

done :- all_full, write('Draw.'), nl.

move1 :- write('Player 1 (o) enter a move: '), read(X), between(1,9,X),  
empty(X), assert(o(X)).
move1:-all_full.
move2 :-  write('Player 2 (x) enter a move: '), read(X), between(1,9,X),  
empty(X),assert(x(X)).
move2:- all_full.
printsquare(N) :- o(N), write(' o ').
printsquare(N) :- x(N), write(' x ').
printsquare(N) :- empty(N), write('   ').

printboard :- printsquare(1),printsquare(2),printsquare(3),nl,
          printsquare(4),printsquare(5),printsquare(6),nl,
          printsquare(7),printsquare(8),printsquare(9),nl.

clear :- x(A), retract(x(A)), fail.
clear :- o(A), retract(o(A)), fail.

play :- not(clear), repeat, move1, printboard, move2,printboard, done.
```

And that`s the error I get:
[Game doesnt stop when player 1 wins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUZO6.png)

Hope you can help me :) Thanks in advance.

Edit: The "Player 2 wins" shows in "done" predicate. After successfull finishing line of 3 'o' or 'x' game should end with either Player 1 wins or Player 2 wins. I`ll include original code, which might help with understanding the problem I get [Original code with comments](http://wdok.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/studium-und-lehre/selbststudium/pgp/slides/ticTacToeCompleteForStudents.pl/view)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @lurker I made an update, hope it helps!

Comment: You have an "open" comment before your `line` predicates (doesn't end with `*/`).

Comment: The problem is that you only check for `done` after BOTH players have moved. You need to check it after EACH player moves. It won't be as simple as inserting a `done`, however (*i.e.*, this won't work: `play :- not(clear), repeat, move1, printboard, done, move2, printboard, done.`), due to your logic. So you'll have to refactor your `play` predicate.

Comment: Thank you @lurker for answering and helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the main predicate of the game:

```
play :- not(clear), repeat, move1, printboard, move2,printboard, done.
```

You do not check for `done` after player's 1 move.

In Prolog's syntax, logical "or" is written as `;`. So one way to express the `play` predicate is:

```
play :- not(clear), repeat, move1, printboard, (done; move2, printboard, done).
```

Which says "after move1, check if the game is done (i.e., finished); if not, player 2 makes the move, and then the check is repeated.